# Cartoon/anime about people transforming into giant white robots to fight aliens

Tags: story-identification, anime, robots, cartoon, mecha

Can anyone name this cartoon movie, which may even have been an anime? I saw it in the 80s or 90s.

Members of a family are able to turn into giant white mecha-looking robots to fight aliens that come to the Earth from outer space. In one part of the movie, they get beaten up by monsters and go into space on their ship to use the sun (like Superman) to help heal them and revive their strength.

Comment: Hi there! :) Maybe you could take a look at these guides on [how to ask a good story-ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028) and [this one for anime-ID](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/98028), see if that triggers any more memories you could [edit] into your question? For instance, did you see that on TV? If so, remember the channel it aired on? Did you watch it in English? Things like that, to increase the chances of a successful identification. Cheers!

Comment: Some things that come to mind are Voltron or one of the early Macross works - Super Dimensional Century: Fortress Macross, Orguss, or Cavalry Southern Cross. I don't remember any of them well enough to pinpoint your description or to really know if these are what you're looking for.